# Unable to place smart banner ad in Android Studio 3.1.4 & app crashes. Which dependencies should I use?

Tags: android

I use sdk version 28

```
 <implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'>
 <implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1
```

Which dependencies should I use for API 28?

I am new to Android.

Comment: Is "Which dependencies I use" a question? Are you asking what dependencies you _should_ use?

Comment: i tried <implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1> but it is not compatible. pl help in details.

Comment: Got the answer. i use <implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'> dependencies.